# How can i save field member value of Scriptable Object when it changed on inspector at runtime?

Tags: unity

Class Foo(monobehavior) has a scriptableObject and it is exposed to Inspector.
When i change its value on inspector on runtime, it is saved.
but when i try to change its value by script on runtime, it is never saved.
what the different?

and is there a way to save changed value of scriptableObject on runtime? without using json.. or something.

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: That's normal Unity behavior. Anything you change in insectors while the game is being tested in the editor gets discarded when you stop the game. I would know a solution, but it only works while you run the game in the editor. It will not work in a built game. Is that OK?

Comment: Does this question help you? [(Unity) Proper way to save ScriptableObjects changed during play mode?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/146552/unity-proper-way-to-save-scriptableobjects-changed-during-play-mode/168457#168457)

Comment: Since you haven't shown us your code, we can't see whether you used Undo.RecordObject to inform the editor that your script has made changes to the object. Can you show us the misbehaving code so we can troubleshoot it?

Comment: @Philipp Yes, but scriptableObject is a Asset. it works like 'material' asset. the changed value in runtime is saved.

Comment: @DMGregory i think there is no misbehaving part on code and it is just a test code. something like 
scriptableObject instance.fieldMember = changedValue.

Comment: And I don't know why, when the field member is a 'Struct', the value is not saved, but when the field member is a 'Class', the value is saved.

Comment: I'll ask you a second time to show your code. Questions that do not contain a minimal, complete, verifiable example are subject to closure.